# Org-babel python with session breaks output

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

If I run the following code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output

  print("   /|")
  print("  / |")
  print(" /  |")
  print("/___|")

#+END_SRC
```

I get the result as expected:

```
#+RESULTS:
:    /|
:   / |
:  /  |
: /___|
```

But if I now run this as part of a session, the result breaks:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session *Python* :results output

  print("   /|")
  print("  / |")
  print(" /  |")
  print("/___|")

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /|
:   / |
:  /  |
: /___|
```

This is what I have in init.el:

```
;; Babel languages
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((emacs-lisp . t)
   (R . t)
   (latex . t)
   (shell . t)
   (php . t)
   (applescript . t)
   (python . t)))

;; Fix Warning "readline" message
(setq python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: IMO :session receives no argument

Comment: That's not true: `:session` takes an argument (it defaults it to something if it is left off). But I think your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU it's caused by a call to org-trim. Updated patch:

```
--- ../../../emacs-20190711/lisp/org/ob-python.el   2019-07-09 16:46:01.274976504 +0200
+++ ob-python.el    2019-08-08 21:51:11.185799006 +0200
@@ -294,7 +294,9 @@
 If RESULT-TYPE equals `output' then return standard output as a
 string.  If RESULT-TYPE equals `value' then return the value of the
 last statement in BODY, as elisp."
-  (let* ((send-wait (lambda () (comint-send-input nil t) (sleep-for 0 5)))
+  (let* ((erg "")
+         (filter-re (concat python-shell-prompt-regexp "\\|" "'org_babel_python_eoe'\n" "\\|" "#.+"))
+         (send-wait (lambda () (comint-send-input nil t) (sleep-for 0 5)))
     (dump-last-value
      (lambda
        (tmp-file pp)
@@ -322,16 +324,17 @@
                   (format org-babel-python--exec-tmpfile
                       tmp-src-file))
               body)))
-          (mapconcat
-       #'org-trim
-       (butlast
+          ;; (mapconcat
+               ;; #'org-trim
+               ;; (butlast
         (org-babel-comint-with-output
             (session org-babel-python-eoe-indicator t body)
           (funcall input-body body)
           (funcall send-wait) (funcall send-wait)
           (insert org-babel-python-eoe-indicator)
           (funcall send-wait))
-        2) "\n")))
+               ;; 2) "\n")
+               ))
             (`value
              (let ((tmp-file (org-babel-temp-file "python-")))
                (org-babel-comint-with-output
@@ -344,6 +347,10 @@
                    (insert org-babel-python-eoe-indicator)
                    (funcall send-wait)))
                (org-babel-eval-read-file tmp-file))))))
+    (when (listp results)
+      (dolist (ele results)
+        (setq erg (concat erg (ignore-errors (replace-regexp-in-string  filter-re "" ele))))))
+    (setq results erg)
     (unless (string= (substring org-babel-python-eoe-indicator 1 -1) results)
       (org-babel-result-cond result-params
    results
```